# How to set JSON tab as the default view for response in SOAP UI Open Source?

Tags: soapui

I am using SOAP UI Open Source for REST API testing. I want to set the JSON tab as the default view for response.

The response I get already has `content-type` set to `'application/json'`. It shows the XML tab and I need to click on JSON to view the response. Is there any way that I can achieve this?

I am using SOAP UI Open Source version 5.4.0.

Comment: This is not possible. You can submit a feature request here: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Feature-Requests/idb-p/SoapUIFeatureRequests

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a brute force teardown script. I had a teardown script on the project level that opens all test steps, switches to the 'Raw' view and takes a screenshot.
Just tested this one against the flikr sample API by pasting it into the testCase teardown script.

It will open all test steps after a test case has been ran and switch view.
The 'SelectView' function takes either an integer (0-4?) or a string "Source", "JSON Response", "HTML Response" or "Raw"
Tested this in SoapUI 5.5 and 5.2.1

For your situation, having a single TestStep per Test Case will basically allow the view to be opened with the desired response tab.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.editor.Editor
import java.awt.Component

def getContainers(Component c) 
{
    Component[] subC = c.getComponents()
    for (Component d : subC) 
    {
        String editorClassName = d.getClass().toString()
        if (editorClassName.contains("ResponseMessageEditor")) 
        {
            ((Editor)d).selectView("JSON Response")
        }
    getContainers(d)
    }

}

def uiSupport = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport

for (tStep in testCase.testStepList) {
    def panel = uiSupport.showDesktopPanel(tStep)
    com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.desktop.maximize(panel)
    getContainers(panel)
}
```